# How to correct styling between Firefox and Chrome/Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I rarely run into these kind of differences between WebKit & Gecko but it is critical to my client. I am not able to adjust the placeholder word "SEARCH" in the search field at the top right of [this site](http://splitlightdesigns.com/megatel/). In Firefox it sits where I want it but in Chrome/Safari it is shifted down. How can I correct this so that it is consistent between browsers?

http://splitlightdesigns.com/megatel/

Many thanks,
Houston

Comment: have you tried line-height ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like chris mentionned in the comments section, `line-height:` is what you're looking for.

I tried it in both chrome and firefox, and a line-height of **26px** fixed the problem. You have to apply it to the input type text. (you can also try it by opening your browser's console and type the new property in the `element.style {}` section.)